# how do you recognize touch events on react native webview?

Tags: react-native, touch, mobile-application, react-native-gesture-handler

Why is longpress event not recognizing the long press event? I have also used gestureHandler component and both are not working.
Can any one point me to relevant documentation or tell me why this code is not recognizing touchevents on the webview component.

```
export default function SiteCard({route, navigation}) {
  const { site } = route.params;
  const [urls, setUrls] = useState({
    url2: site,
  })
  const webViewRef = useRef();

  const onLongPress = (event) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
      alert("I've been pressed for 800 milliseconds");
    }
  };

  return (
    <LongPressGestureHandler
    onHandlerStateChange={onLongPress}
    minDurationMs={200}
  >
    <ScrollView scrollEnabled={false}
    style={styles.tab}
    level='1'>
    <View>
      <WebView
          source={{ uri: urls.url2 }}
          style={styles.PageView}
          ref={webViewRef}
        />
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </LongPressGestureHandler>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  PageView: {
    height: 800,
  }
});
```